# Why does svnserve still ask for password via svn+ssh when sasl is used?

Tags: ssh, svn, sasl, svnserve

I have `svnserve` configured to run from `inetd` and `svnserve.conf` set to use sasl for authentication. This is so I could allow access to some repositories by users who do not have system-wide accounts using `svn://`.

However, for users who do have a system account (such as myself), I prefer to use `svn+ssh://` for the public key authentication. It was my understanding that when run as `svnserve -t`, svnserve would not ask for authentication and would use the SSH-authenticated current user. I feel like this used to work. Today when I went to update a working copy I had using the `svn+ssh://` repository path it started asking me for a password.

I was able to confirm that it is not SSH asking me for the password, the public key authentication is succeeding, it is svnserve/sasl asking me for a password. If I turn off sasl, it seems to work as expected, but I prefer sasl over the plaintext password file. I'm not sure if this never worked or it was broken by a recent upgrade that I didn't notice. This is with subversion 1.9.4 on Debian stretch.

Comment: It sounds like you should be asked for a password. But I have no idea. Where did you get this idea that it should work that way?

Comment: from the svnserve man page: "-t, --tunnel Causes svnserve to run in tunnel mode, which is just like the inetd mode of operation (serve one connection  over stdin/stdout) except that the connection is considered to be pre-authenticated with the username of the current uid."

Also, the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) "When using svn+ssh:// URLs to access a repository, remember that it's the ssh program prompting for authentication, and not the svn client program."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the `svnserve` source, I found the answer. Even with `-t`, it still delegates to sasl to authenticate, it's just that external authentication via the SSH user is now an option. But to make that work, I had to add `EXTERNAL` as an allowed mechanism to the `mech_list` in my `/usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf` file.